# MySQL query - where search with empty variable

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably elementary thing, but I can't find answer anywhere.
I need to use WHERE that equals a variable I get from POST.

But I don't know if the variable is empty or not. I have a lot of parameters to use in query, but not every is entered. Do I have to use some if/else, or I can search through database with empty variable?

If parameter variable is not empty, I want to find rows with this in databse. If is empty, I want to get all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$db->query("SELECT field FROM table WHERE filter = '" . (isset($_POST['field']) ? $db->real_escape_string($_POST['field']) : "") . "'");
```

This prevents notices, if the POST variable is not set. You can just use this, if the variable is set (just as normal):

```
$db->query("SELECT field FROM table WHERE filter = '" . $db->real_escape_string($_POST['field']) . "'");
```

Also, you can use this with prepared statements etc.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work. If the variable is empty, i want to get everything.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just make an `if(!empty($_POST['field']))` before the query, and repeat the query in `else` but leave the `WHERE` condition out. That should do what you want. (Or you just put the WHERE statement in a variable if needed - thats even shorter.)